# How to set tags-table-list in emacs?

Tags: emacs, tags

I use tags table. and wanted to set the tags-table-list variable. I did the following in .emacs

`;; tags DB
(let 
  (
    (default-directory "/home/uid/")
  )
  (setq tags-table-list (expand-file-name "project/TAGS"))
)`

But when I load tags in emacs, it reports the following

Wrong type argument: stringp, 47

It works if I simply set the following
   (setq tags-table-list '("/home/uid/project/TAGS"))

I am not sure if this is an emacs lisp issue or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tags-table-list` needs a list value, not a string value. So your second sexp is correct: `(setq tags-table-list '("/home/uid/project/TAGS"))`, but not your first sexp: `(setq tags-table-list (expand-file-name "project/TAGS"))`.

Check `C-h v tags-table-list` to see the description.

You can also use this:

```
(setq tags-table-list (list (expand-file-name "project/TAGS")))
```